# Drivers installation history

Tags: windows-8, drivers, logging

How can I check a history of drivers installation on Windows 8?

For example I know that in the last week someone installed new drivers. How can I check what drivers were installed and for what equipment?

Is it possible to do this with event logs (Event Viewer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I check a history of driver installation on Windows 8?

You can use [DriverView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html) from [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/):

> DriverView utility displays the list of all device drivers currently loaded on your system. For each driver in the list, additional useful information is displayed: load address of the driver, description, version, product name, company that created the driver, and more.

Restriction:

- Only **loaded drivers** are displayed.

Displayed information includes "Created Date" and "Modified Date".

- "Created Date" is the installation date.
- "Modified Date" is the last update date.

Example screenshot from my laptop (sorted by most recent "Modified Date"):

[image]

Note:

- Other columns are available, I've removed some to reduce the width of the image and left the more interesting ones.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [NirSoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.